# Turn off automatic loading of images in windows 10 Mail

Tags: email, windows-10

The Windows 10 email client automatically loads all images in emails.  This is bad as it can be used for spammers to verify that they've reached a valid email address.  Is there any way to turn this off?  There was in the Windows 8.x email client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft at every update seems to change how their programs work modifying settings, UI, and adding confusion...

I still had the same issue (April 2019, Windows 10 1809) 'till I finally found a "hidden" setting to enable/disable the automatic image downloading in Mail:

*Settings (gear icon) > Reading pane > External content > Automatically download external images and style formats except S/MIME Mail = **OFF***

N.B.: of course you can still manually download the full message and images clicking at the bottom of every mail on the small placeholder "Download message and pictures"

Comment: "Download message and pictures" seems missing now :( I want to download the images specifically for some messages only

Comment: The above path description to disable "Automatically download external images and style formats except S/MIME Mail" is still there for me, April 2020 Win 10 2020.

Comment: I was referring to download manually part bro

Comment: It's still there that too for me.

Comment: A screenshot and the version of Mail will be more helpful bro

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/cwQYr7y), Win 10 1909 up-to-date.

Comment: Updated windows and "Download message and pictures" is still missing :( . My mail's version is 16005.11029.20108.0. Anyway thanks bro for the help

Comment: I actually set "Automatically download external images and style formats **for** S/MIME Mail = OFF", My bad bro, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way to do this in the email app on Windows 10

go to Settings> Account> Change mailbox Sync Settings> Uncheck " Always download full message and Internet images"

Comment: Unfortunately disabling "Always download full message and Internet images" has *no effect* for me (app version 17.6769.40791.0). Images still load. A bug? Who knows.

Comment: Update: somehow it's now working *partially* (same version). It doesn't display the whole mail and shows a link "Download message and pictures". But some images are loaded. Seems like the mail is downloaded partially, including some external content.

Comment: It's 2018 and the situation has not changed. Sad.

Answer (score 2):

To say the least, **you can't**.

I just tried like my life depended on it to figure out how it could be possible but I think this statement sums up the Windows 10 mail app:

> ... (the) Windows 10 Mail has bugs and features that should be included but aren’t. Frustratingly, **some basic but useful parts of Windows 8.1 Mail were stripped out in this new version**.

[Windows 10 Mail: Beautiful but bug-ridden](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/07/windows-10-mail-its-got-bugs-and-missing-features-but-it-looks-nice/)

---

However, in the event you switch to something like Outlook 2010 or 2013 you can still do it there.

> Outlook File menu
>
> Options then Trust Center
>
> Trust Center Settings
>
> Automatic Download: mark the box that says “**Don’t download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items**”: